# Why can number type in ORACLE scale up to 127?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, number-formatting

If the precision takes up to 38 digits, why do we need 127 digit scale for number type?

Isn't 37 is the maximum?

I.e. `Number(38,37) := 1.123344444...` up to 37 digit?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a scale that goes further than the precision.

For example a `number(38,40)`:

```
0.003344444...
```

Or a `number(38,42)` (note that `0.003344444` as a value would fail for this type):

```
0.00003344444...
```

This means that if the precision is less than the scale, the actual number will be digits only.

Comment: Hmm.. It gave error value error... But it worked only in case of( scale-precision)  put zeros as the times as result

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `declare x number(38,42) := 0.0000123456; begin dbms_output.put_line(x); end;` works as intended.